# how to get a unqiue result sets in PL/SQL cursor?

Tags: plsql, cursor, unique, distinct

I want use this procedure to display the username and moblephone number,the result sets is this when I use select :

declare [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lO52u.png)

when the procedure runs,I  get this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Qnq9.png)

> error ORA-01722: invalid number
>    ORA-06512: at "ABPROD.SHAREPOOL", line 24.

when I use unique or distinct in the cursor,nothing display.
the code source :

```
create or replace procedure sharepool (assignment  in varchar2,myorgname in varchar2)  is
rightid   T_CLM_AP30_RIGHT.RIGHT_ID%type;
orgid t_clm_ap30_org.org_id%type;

begin

  select t.right_id  into rightid   from T_CLM_AP30_RIGHT t where t.rightdesc=trim(assignment);
dbms_output.put_line(rightid||trim(myorgname)||assignment);
  select t.org_id into orgid  from t_clm_ap30_org t  where t.orgname=trim(myorgname);
  dbms_output.put_line(orgid);

      declare 
      cursor namelist  is select distinct a.username,a.mobile from t_clm_ap30_user a, T_CLM_AP30_RIGHT_AUTH t where a.user_id=t.user_id and t.right_id=rightid and  t.poolorgrange=orgid ;
      begin 
        for c in namelist
          loop

            dbms_output.put_line(c.username||'   '||c.mobile);
            end loop;
        end;



end sharepool;
```

Comment: The code you've posted here clearly isn't the code you're executing so it's really not clear how you're expecting us to help. All we can say is that INVALID_NUMBER errors indicate a failed casting of a string to a number. Probably that means one of your join conditions is comparing a string column with a number column, and you have values in the string column which cannot be cast to a number.

Comment: I have post my full code.when I run it ,I got this :ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at "ABPROD.SHAREPOOL", line 24
ORA-06512: at line 1

Answer (score 1):

`INVALID_NUMBER` errors indicate a failed casting of a string to a number. That means one of your join conditions is comparing a string column with a number column, and you have values in the string column which cannot be cast to a number.

> ORA-06512: at "ABPROD.SHAREPOOL", line 24

Line 24 doesn't align with the code you've posted, presumably lost in translation from your actual source. Also you haven't posted table descriptions so we cannot tell which columns to look at.

So here is a guess.

One (or more) of these joins has an implicit numeric conversion:

```
where a.user_id = t.user_id 
and t.right_id = rightid 
and  t.poolorgrange = orgid
```

That is, either  `t_clm_ap30_user.user_id` is numeric and `T_CLM_AP30_RIGHT_AUTH.user_id` is not, or vice versa. Or `T_CLM_AP30_RIGHT_AUTH.right_id` is numeric and `T_CLM_AP30_RIGHT.right_id` is not, or vice versa. Or `T_CLM_AP30_RIGHT_AUTH.poolorgrange` is numeric and `t_clm_ap30_org.org_id` is not, or vice versa.

Only you can figure this out, because only you can see your schema. Once you have identified the join where you have a string column being compared to a numeric column you need to query that column to find the data which cannot be converted to a number.

Let's say that `T_CLM_AP30_RIGHT_AUTH.poolorgrange` is the rogue string. You can see which are the troublesome rows with this query:

```
select * from T_CLM_AP30_RIGHT_AUTH
where translate (poolorgrange, 'x1234567890', 'x') is not null;
```

The `translate()` function strips out digits. So anything which is left can't be converted to a number.

> "T_CLM_AP30_RIGHT_AUTH.poolorgrange is varchar2,and t_clm_ap30_org.org_id is numeric ."

You can avoid the error by explicitly casting the `t_clm_ap30_org.org_id` to a string:

```
select distinct a.username, a.mobile 
from t_clm_ap30_user a, 
    T_CLM_AP30_RIGHT_AUTH t 
where a.user_id = t.user_id 
and t.right_id = rightid 
and  t.poolorgrange = to_char(orgid) ;
```

Obviously you're not going to get matches on those alphanumeric values but the query will run.

Comment: thank you .you are right.T_CLM_AP30_RIGHT_AUTH.poolorgrange is varchar2,and t_clm_ap30_org.org_id is numeric .